# How to do a DOM sort of a UL with TypeScript in Angular2+ (without using ngFor)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a case where I have a list of declared properties that i need to sort dynamically.  Most examples that you find our using ngFor, but in this case, my list is declared on the page.  How can you via TypeScript (or JavaScript) sort this DOM list by a given property, such as priority?

An example HTML list:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="list-item3" priority="2">text 1</li>
    <li id="list-item4" priority="3">text 2</li>
    <li id="list-item2" priority="4">text 3</li>
    <li id="list-item1" priority="1">text 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does your actual list look like this? Because that can be done with `ngFor`. Also: if the list is declared on the page, why isn't it sorted in the markup? Does the sorting depend on bound properties?

Comment: I stated in the question title that I can't do this with a ngFor